# retrive specific record from dynamic DB table created through PHP,HTML

Tags: php, html, database, dom

I'm retrieving data from database and presenting it in tables on web page. Like gmail, mails list. Now I want to open specific mail on clicking data row of table which holds minor details of data record.

I want when I click on specific row of table generated by query. It will pass the 'id' of data record/row to linked page(mail.PHP). Or any other way of this problem???

```
 <?php
      if( mysql_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 ){
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
      }else{
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) ){
          echo "<tr ><td ><a href='mail.php'>Mail from {$row['from']} on {$row['date']}.</a></td></tr>\n";
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: `echo "<tr ><td ><a href='mail.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Mail from {$row['from']} on {$row['date']}.</a></td></tr>\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Rozas in the comments gave you the answer:

```
echo "<tr ><td ><a href='mail.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Mail from {$row['from']} on {$row['date']}.</a></td></tr>\n";
```

In the code for mail.php, you need to examine the html form post parameters, obtain the value of the ID, if empty, display the list, if it has a value, query for the message with that ID, and display the message.